# How to refer the center of a giant component to an external coordinate system?

Tags: grid, center, networkx, mathematical-lattices

I am working in Python (package: `NetworkX`) with a network of, say, `100` nodes. I create it and then fragment it by removing a fraction of its nodes (`removal`), as shown below. The script computes the length of the largest component and its center node(s).

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
N = 10
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
pos = {y:x for x,y in labels.iteritems()}
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 300)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
plt.close()
removal=numpy.array([1,5,18,23,54,8,36,95,41,75,77,56,29,39,81,76,27,34,52,50,53,64,45,85])
G.remove_nodes_from(removal)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 300)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
giant = max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key=len) #The largest component
center_nodes = nx.center(giant) #The center node(s)
print len(giant)
print center_nodes
```

This gives me:
`len(giant)=29` and `center_nodes=[12,13]`.

What the network looks like after removal:
[image]

My network is embedded in a 2D grid which measures `(N+1)x(N+1)`, and has its own coordinate system. Every node of the network is to be seen as if it was placed **at the intersection** of each cell in the grid below:

[image]

**My problem:** How can I "translate" the result given by `center_nodes=[12,13]` into the location of **cell A** in the grid? In this case, I would like to have `center_nodes=[12,13] -> center_coord=13`.

**PS:** if I change `removal`, `len(center_nodes)` changes, as does the shape of the connected subgraphs. Thus, **cell A** will not be in the same position as above. To account for this, I would like to be able to always get the grid coordinates of the cell at the top left corner of the `center_nodes` cluster, regardless of its shape and location within the network.